# How to create Vaadin tabsheet without components?

Tags: java, tabs, vaadin, ttabsheet

I need the functionality of a Vaadin Tabsheet. But don't need a component for each tab.

Instead, I have only one component (separate table) and it will be manipulated with the tab sheet actions. For now, I have assigned hidden labels to tabs.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Probably you just should not use the tabsheet component for this. If the content is always the same, why not just display the table and above it you show styled buttons which act as the tab sheets?

Comment: well, I thought of that. But the user should feel this is a tabsheet. I am using almost all functionalities of tabsheet (add, remove, select, find the selected one, giving the user freedom to create, delete tabs, etc). I feel like implementing all of these is a waste of time.  
Isn't there a way to hack my way out of this? :/

Comment: Then just add your table on the active tab and remove it when the tab is inactive

Comment: ... or just addComponent the only table to the active tab.  a component can only have one parent and it will be moved to where ever it will be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone one ran into the same scenario, here is how I solved it.

Instead of adding hidden labels, I added labels without captions.so no need to hide them, because they have nothing to show. :).

Don't set their visibility to hidden. It will cause problems since Vaadin doesn't send hidden components to the client.